# Entity framework find doesn't work and i don't know why

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, find, dbcontext

I am actually working on an existing project that works with entity Framework, it works with code first, I have added 2 entities, a "Profil" entity and an "ActionHyperV" entity with a many to many Relationship, I correctly have migrate the existing database and my tables have been created, also the ProfilActionHyperVs table that link my two entities. 
Here are my two entities :

```
public class Profil
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Nom { get; set; }
    [StringLength(250)]
    public string Commentaire { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ActionHyperV> ActionHyperVs { get; set; }
}


public class ActionHyperV
{

    public int Id{ get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Nom { get; set; }
    [StringLength(250)]
    public string Commentaire { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Profil> Profils { get; set; }
}
```

I can have the content of my tables if I do Something like this :

```
List<Profil> profils = ctx.Profils.ToList();
```

It works.

But what I want to do is to link my tables, so I do like this :

```
public bool LinkProfilAction(/*int ProfilID, int ActionID*/)
        {

                using (Context ctx = this._contextProvider.GetContext())
                {

                int ProfilID = 1;
                int ActionID = 1;

                var profil = ctx.Profils.Find(ProfilID);
                var action = ctx.ActionHyperV.Find(ActionID);


                profil.ActionHyperVs.Add(action);

                ctx.SaveChanges();
                return true;

                }


        }
```

It is Something that work if I do it on tables that existed before but not on the Profil and ActionHyperV tables, the find return null, I don't know why because I have fill my tables and I use correct Ids to look for my data.
I have try to do like in the following tutorial in the insert section that is exactly what I want to do, but it does the same thing.

If you have an idea what's wrong it would be really helpfull.
Thank you!

Comment: What exactly happens with this code? Are you getting any error? What error?

Comment: do you have a mapping table? (many to many)

Comment: The only error i get is this : The obect reference is not defined to an object instance when I do profil.ActionHyperVs.Add(action)

Comment: Sounds like it did not find a record for ActionID.  Why are you trying to add the same record to the table?  Don't you want to add.a new one?

Comment: Have you defined your `Profil` primary key / property? I only see some length constrains...

Comment: Are you sure `profil` is `null`? I suspect `profil.ActionHyperVs` collection is null since you are not initializing it and also it's not `virtual` (i.e. no lazy loading)

Comment: Yes I have a mapping table, 
I just want to link an action to a profil not add an action or a profil.
Yes the primary key is auto defined, it is good a primary key in my db.

Comment: Profil has the value : {Unis.ISMC.Core.Entities.Profil}

Comment: Read my previous comment. What happens if you change `public ICollection<ActionHyperV> ActionHyperVs { get; set; }` to `public ICollection<ActionHyperV> ActionHyperVs { get; set; } = new List<ActionHyperV>();` ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have forget to add virtual attribut to your collection. Entity Framework using Proxy pattern that need to override your class.
Try this :

```
public virtual ICollection<ActionHyperV> ActionHyperVs { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<Profil> Profils { get; set; }
```

Comment: Nice ! You're welcome. Don't forget to mark answer as solution.  ;)